# RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (URL, Request,Class<String>)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I cannot `post` a request with `RestTemplate`. It show following error on line

```
The method postForObject(URI, Object, Class<T>) in the type RestTemplate is 
not applicable for the arguments (URL, Request, 
 Class<String>)
```

**Code**

```
        URL url = new URL("http://testnl.etbxml.com/api");
        Authentication auth = new Authentication("Test", "test");
        auth.setFunction("SearchAvailability");

        Request req = new Request("test");
        req.setAuth(auth);
        req.setCityid(23);
        req.setStartdate("2015-11-20");
        req.setEnddate("2015-11-29");
        req.setRating(4);
        req.setNoofpersons(2);
        req.setLanguage("en");
        req.setCurrency("EUR");
        req.setCustomerIP(MY_IP);
        req.setAuth(auth);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        //restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        //restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        //String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, req, EasyToBook.class);
        //Line 21
        Easytobook ea = restTemplate.postForObject(url, req, String.class);

        auth.setFunction("SearchAvailability");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) instance but `RestTemplate` expects an object of type [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).

Just replace this line:

```
URL url = new URL("http://testnl.etbxml.com/api");
```

With this line:

```
URI url = new URI("http://testnl.etbxml.com/api");
```

This should do the trick.